# How to upgrade all dependancies of my project during development

Tags: python, virtualenv, upgrade, setuptools

I'm developing project using virtualenv and i haven't found a method to upgrade all of my project dependancies.

Lets say I have no dependancies to my project yet, and i need to use sqlachemy, I will add

```
install_requires=["foo_lib"]
```

in my setup.py file then i'll run python setup.py develop.
This will install the latest version of foo_lib. then when i will distribute my code, the user will download the latest version of foo_lib.

Lets say now that foo_lib goes from 0.1 to 0.2.

I will still user foo_lib-0.1 but users will use my code with foolib-0.2.

What i need is the right way to upgrade all my libs respecting the eventual limitations setted in install_requires (eg => install_requires["foo_lib", "bar_lib==0.5"])
i want to run python setup.py  to go to the last version of foo_lib but keep my version 0.5 of bar_lib).

The only way i have found to achieve this so far is to destroy the whole virtualenv and then run python seup.py develop on a new venv.